# Python: detecting existing file : os.file.exists

Tags: python

I'm obviously doing something very wrong. I'd like to find files, that are in one directory but not in second directory (for instance xxx.phn in one directory and xxx.wav in second directory...

IT seems that I cannot detect, when file is NOT present in second directory (it's always showing like all files are)... I don't get any file displayed, although they exist...

```
import shutil, random, os, sys

if len(sys.argv) < 4:
    print """usage: python del_orphans_dir1_dir2.py source_folder source_ext dest_folder dest_ext
             """
    sys.exit(-1)

folder = sys.argv[1]
ext  = sys.argv[2]
dest_folder = sys.argv[3]
dest_ext  = sys.argv[4]
i = 0

for d, ds, fs in os.walk(folder):
    for fname in fs:
        basename = os.path.splitext(fname)[0]
        if (not os.path.exists(dest_folder+'/'+basename + '.' + dest_ext) ):
            print str(i)+': No duplicate for: '+fname
            i=i+1      

print str(i)+' files found'
```

Comment: FWIW There's no need to do the `str(i)` call.  Just do `print i, " files found"`.  And `i+=1` rather than `i=i+1` works.

Comment: If `os.path.exists` doesn't work correctly, why do you need more than one or two lines to demonstrate same? Having the extra code just creates other places (not related to `os.path.exists`) the bug could hide.

Comment: Similarly, recalculating the full name once for your print statement and again for the actual `exists()` call means that there could be a subtle difference between them. Ideally, a question like this would show `ls -l` on the output from the print showing the file to exist, and an error message from the script showing it not to, and would use a variable assigned only once for both the print call and the `exists()` call, to avoid any chance of such bugs.

Comment: I have unequal number of files in two directories. And still, script repors '0 files found'. I can remove that print but this doesn't solve the problem...

Comment: @user2064070. Please edit your question to show the output from `print sys.argv[1:]`, and also `for x in os.walk(path): print x` for both `folder` and `dest_folder`. (You might want to try setting up some test folders with only a few files in before doing this, though).

Comment: The path isn't given by fname. That's just the filename. The source path is: path = os.path.join(d, fname)

To actually get a proper relative path: relpath = os.relpath(path, folder)

As suggested, print out the source path, the relative path, the dest path, and you'll soon see where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest that you make the filename you're looking at checking and print it before checking whether it exists..

```
dest_fname = dest_folder+'/'+basename + '.' + dest_ext
print "dest exists? %s" % dest_fname
os.path.exists(dest_fname)
```

Also as an aside please join paths using the join() method.  (If you really want the basename without the leading path elements there's a basename() function).

Comment: No, [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html#os.walk) does not work that way: `fname` will always be a filename, not a path. And in any case, the OPs code is testing whether the file *doesn't* exist, but that is evaluating to `False` for every file. That is why the final output is `'0 files found'` (i.e. no duplicates were found).

Comment: True.. I'll edit out the misleading stuff.  I still think he should print the paths he's looking for.  Probably more of a comment than an answer now..

Answer (score 0):

I tried your program out and it worked for two simple flat directories.  Here are the directory contents:

```
a\a.txt
a\b.txt      # Missing from b directory
a\c.txt
b\a.csv
b\c.csv
```

And result of your script with `a txt b csv` as parameters.  If your result was different, maybe you used different parameters?

```
0: No duplicate for: b.txt
1 files found
```

But when I added subdirectories:

```
a\a.txt
a\b.txt      # Missing from b directory
a\c.txt
a\c\d.txt
a\c\e.txt    # Missing from b\c directory
b\a.csv
b\c.csv
b\c\d.csv
```

Your script gives:

```
0: No duplicate for: b.txt
1: No duplicate for: d.txt      # Error here
2: No duplicate for: e.txt
3 files found
```

To work with sub-directories you need to compute the path relative to the source directory, and then add it to the destination directory.  Here's the result with a few other minor cleanups and prints to see what is going on.  Note that `fname` is always just the file name and needs to be joined with `d` to get the whole path:

```
#!python2
import os, sys

if len(sys.argv) < 4:
    print """usage: python del_orphans_dir1_dir2.py source_folder source_ext dest_folder dest_ext
             """
    sys.exit(-1)

folder = sys.argv[1]
ext  = sys.argv[2]
dest_folder = sys.argv[3]
dest_ext  = sys.argv[4]
i = 0

for d, ds, fs in os.walk(folder):
    for fname in fs:
        relpath = os.path.relpath(os.path.join(d,fname),folder)
        relbase = os.path.splitext(relpath)[0]
        path_to_check = os.path.join(dest_folder,relbase+'.'+dest_ext)
        if not os.path.exists(path_to_check):
            print '{}: No duplicate for: {}, {} not found.'.format(i,os.path.join(folder,relpath),path_to_check)
            i += 1

print i,'files found'
```

Output:

```
0: No duplicate for: a\b.txt, b\b.csv not found.
1: No duplicate for: a\c\e.txt, b\c\e.csv not found.
2 files found
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is looking for are matching files, not duplicate ones. One problem is that you're not using use the `source_ext` argument when searching. Another is I think the command-line argument handling is messed-up. Here's a corrected version that accomplishes what you're trying to do:

```
import os
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 5:
    print("usage: python "
          "del_orphans_dir1_dir2.py "  # argv[0] (script name)
          "source_folder "             # argv[1]
          "source_ext "                # argv[2]
          "dest_folder "               # argv[3]
          "dest_ext")                  # argv[4]
    sys.exit(2)  # command line error

source_folder, source_ext, dest_folder, dest_ext = sys.argv[1:6]
dest_ext = dest_ext if dest_ext.startswith('.') else '.'+dest_ext  # check dot

found = 0
for d, ds, fs in os.walk(source_folder):
    for i, fname in enumerate(fs, start=1):
        basename, ext = os.path.splitext(fname)
        if ext == source_ext:
           if os.path.exists(os.path.join(dest_folder, basename+dest_ext)):
                found += 1
           else:
                print '{}: No matching file found for: {}'.format(i, fname)

print '{} matches found'.format(found)
sys.exit(0)
```